# Angular routes giving 404 error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute, angularjs-ng-route

I'm getting 404 errors when I try to click through my angular routes, and I'm not sure whats wrong.  I have these links:

```
<a href="/">Home</a>
<a href="/portfolio">Portfolio</a>
<a href="/about">About</a>
<a href="/travel">Travel</a>
```

And the routes are set up here in routes.js

```
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider 
    .when('/', { 
        templateUrl: 'home.html',
        controller: 'mainController'
    })

    .when('/portfolio', { 
        templateUrl: 'portfolio.html',
        controller: 'mainController'
    })

    .when('/about', { 
        templateUrl: 'about.html',
        controller: 'mainController'
    })

    .when('/travel', { 
        templateUrl: 'travels.html',
        controller: 'mainController'
    });
});
```

My understanding is that when I click on the `<a href="/about"></a>`, for instance, the controller will look for `/about` in the routes provider.  Then it will see that the template `about.html` fills that request, and then `about.html` will fill into `ng-view`.  The request is just giving me a 404 at `http://localhost:8000/about`, though.  What am I doing wrong?

Getting no errors, but here's the rest of my angular app for reference:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);
app.controller('mainController', ['$scope', '$routeParams', function($scope, $routeParams) { }]);
```

And the HTML

```
    <div class="mountainSection">
        <div class="ang-wrap" ng-view></div>
    </div>

    <div class="controlPanel">
        <div class="buttonWrap">
            <div class="home button">
                <a href="/">Home</a>
            </div>
            <div class="divider">|</div>
            <div class="portfolio button">
                <a href="/portfolio">Portfolio</a>
            </div>
            <div class="divider">|</div>
            <div class="about button">
                <a href="/about">About</a>
            </div>
            <div class="divider">|</div>
            <div class="intl button">
                <a href="/travel">Travel</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: change `about.html ` to `about` in your route config

Comment: That snuck into the question from my debugging, sorry.  Does not fix the error.

Comment: so what you try to achieve ?

Comment: try using hash tag in href.<a href="#/about">About</a>@VirgeAssault

Comment: That worked, thank you!